# Error when uploading video to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using the paperclip and paperclip-av-transcoder in my rails app and I have gotten to the point where I can upload videos locally. But when I try it in heroku I get this error. Av::UnableToDetect (Unable to detect any supported library):

I may have to add something to make it work with s3 but I had it working with images earlier so everything should be setup for s3.

This is the code in my model

```
class Classvideo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :video, :styles => { 
        :medium => {:geometry => "640x480", :format => 'flv'},
        :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }
    }, :processors => [:transcoder]

validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => ["video/mp4", "video.mov", "video/mpeg","video/mpeg4", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"]
end
```

Comment: I have the same problem... Have you found any solution ?

I've tried to setup s3 here in model but it doesn't change anything.
I get the impression that the problem is :processors => [:transcoder]. The "library" should be :transcoder if I'm right...

Comment: @CorentinGeoffray I didn't find a solution to the ffmpeg problem but I was finally able to upload videos locally and to heroku. I changed the code in my model a little bit from what I had had previously (before I started using ffmpeg) and it seemed to work the second way. The first time I had styling on the video and it didn't seem to like that. I think that is the only thing I took out and it now seems to work.

Comment: has_attached_file :video
 
validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => ["video/mp4",  "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"]

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you just need to **install ffmpeg**

For example on OS-X: http://www.renevolution.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x/

And then on heroku https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue just this past week - Try this!

```
Video model:
    has_attached_file :video, styles: {
        :medium => {
          :geometry => "640x480",
          :format => 'mp4'
        },
        :thumb => { :geometry => "160x120", :format => 'jpeg', :time => 10}
    }, :processors => [:transcoder]
    validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
```

Make sure you already bundled:

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'
gem "paperclip-ffmpeg", "~> 1.2.0"
```

Run the paperclip migration:

```
rails g paperclip model video
```

Be sure to add in post_controller.rb:

```
private

    def bscenes_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:video)
    end
```

Upload form:

```
<%= f.file_field :video %>
```

Show page:

```
<%= video_tag bscene.video.url(:medium), controls: true, style: "max-width: 100%;" %>
```

At this point you should get this error:

> Av::UnableToDetect (Unable to detect any supported library):

Go to your terminal and type in:

```
brew options ffmpeg
```

Then run the following to install ffmpeg:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-libass --with-libvo-aacenc --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openjpeg --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-schroedinger --with-speex --with-theora --with-tools
```

**Restart your server and try to upload a video now! Hope this helps - Happy coding :)**